# Which hash is returned by One Drive Business?

Tags: hash, office365, xor, onedrive

I am implementing a sync process for one drive and one drive business.

For that I require hashes for files stored on one drive.

For one drive SHA1 hash is returned, and the site says that no hash is returned for one drive business, but, when I make a call to get meta data for an item, it shows a `quickxorhash` field.

So is this hash reliable to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're in the process of updating the documentation, but yes you can trust the `quickXorHash`.