# OneDrive for Business quickXorHash

Tags: office365, onedrive

How do I compute OneDrive quickXorHash locally, so that I can verify files I upload? Is there some kind of specification on how to compute it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no document about the quickXorHash at present, but the Microsoft is building the document(refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861331/which-hash-is-returned-by-one-drive-business))

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is now explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/code-snippets/quickxorhash)

```
method block zero():
     returns a block with all zero bits.

   method block reverse(block b)
     returns a block with all of the bytes reversed (00010203... => ...03020100)

   method block extend8(byte b):
     returns a block with all zero bits except for the lower 8 bits which come from b.

   method block extend64(int64 i):
     returns a block of all zero bits except for the lower 64 bits which come from i
     and are in little-endian byte order.

   method block rotate(block bl, int n):
     returns bl rotated left by n bits.

   method block xor(block bl1, block bl2):
     returns a bitwise xor of bl1 with bl2

   method block XorHash0(byte[] rgb):
     block ret = zero()
     for (int i = 0; i < rgb.Length; i ++)
       ret = xor(ret, rotate(extend8(rgb[i]), i * 11))
     returns reverse(ret)

   entrypoint block XorHash(byte[] rgb):
     returns xor(extend64(rgb.Length), XorHash0(rgb))
```